# Using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value for field with ORMLite and SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite with Androids integrated sqlite database and I'm trying to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value for a field.
I've tried:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "tableone")
public class TableOne {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "id")
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "created", defaultValue = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private java.util.Date created;

    public TableOne() {

    }
}
```

the generated ormlite_config.txt:

```
# --table-start--
dataClass=com.test.ormlite.TableOne
tableName=tableone
# --table-fields-start--
# --field-start--
fieldName=id
columnName=id
generatedId=true
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=created
columnName=created
defaultValue=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
# --field-end--
# --table-fields-end--
# --table-end--
#################################
```

but I got an SQLException with the following stacktrace:

```
W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: Problems with field FieldType:name=created,class=TableOne parsing default date-string 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' using 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'
    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.types.DateStringType.parseDefaultString(DateStringType.java:46)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.assignDataType(FieldType.java:1067)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.<init>(FieldType.java:274)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.convertFieldConfigs(DatabaseTableConfig.java:236)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.extractFieldTypes(DatabaseTableConfig.java:101)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:153)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:128)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:119)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.doCreateDao(DaoManager.java:359)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDaoFromConfig(DaoManager.java:326)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:55)
    at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getDao(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:279)
    at com.fibus.ormlite.database.ORMOpenDatabaseHelper.getTableOneDao(ORMOpenDatabaseHelper.java:47)
    at com.fibus.ormlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" (at offset 0)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:571)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.types.BaseDateType.normalizeDateString(BaseDateType.java:47)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.types.DateStringType.parseDefaultString(DateStringType.java:44)
    ... 28 more
```

I've also tried setting the format to `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'` to match `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`s format and specifying the dataType as `DataType.DATE_STRING` but with the same results.
It seems to me that ormlite is trying to parse the string `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a date since the doc says:

> defaultValue
>
> String default value of the field when we are creating a new row in the table. Default is none.

If that's the case is there a way to prevent this or an other way to set the default value? I've tried `version = true` as well but I don't want the field to be updated whenever the row is updated.

I have searched SO and the web but wasn't able to find a way to solve this problem.

Android version 2.2
ORMLite version 4.48
SQLite version 3.6.22

Answer (score 0):

You can work around issue with custom persister: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#Custom-Persisters. Start with existing one - com.j256.ormlite.field.typesDateType, and update it's parseDefaultString() method to handle CURRENT_TIMESTAMP string and set current time on java side, not sqlite side